# How to create an API server with endpoints in Python?

Tags: python, rest

Using Python, I would like to create an API server with the following endpoints:

`/metric` - needs to return the number of times the API server has been called

`/health` - needs to return `ok`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify any framework ou give any initial code, here's a simple example using Flask on how it would be:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
count = 0

@app.route('/metric')
def metric():
    global count
    count += 1
    return str(count)

@app.route('/healthz')
def health():
    return "ok"

app.run()
```

To install Flask, run:

```sh
pip3 install flask
```

Run the python code and access on your browser `http://127.0.0.1:5000/metric` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/healthz`

Comment: thank you....I am new to building endpoints on python. this makes me understand the whole scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) is a great option. FastAPI is a "fast (high-performance), web framework for building APIs". It provides [interactive API documentation (provided by Swagger UI)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#interactive-api-docs) to visualize and interact with the API’s resources.

### Working Example

You can access the interactive API autodocs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs. You can also access the API endpoints directly from the browser at, for instance, http://127.0.0.1:8000/metric.

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
hits = 0

@app.get("/metric")
async def metric():
    global hits
    hits+=1
    return {"hits": hits}

@app.get("/health")
async def health():
    return "ok"
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.. I see you used uvicorn to import fastapi...also I noticed you used async , Just a ques, so if we dont use async you think the code will work?

Comment: Yes, it would work. In brief, when you declare an endpoint with normal `def` instead of `async def`, it is run in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `def` vs `async def`.